# click particular region of image

Tags: javascript, html

I want to click a circle region of a image, which jpg or png. 
is there anyway to do this without using imagemap?

this clickable image is visible, after click center of that image, I want to display another image with a popup style  new windows.

this page is html, so better to do it with JavaScript.

I forget to metion, the image is in circle shape, and it keep spanning all the time. I think this might bring some trouble.

Comment: If you do this using javascript it isn't guaranteed to work for all of your users, much better to do an imagemap just for the sake of those users who don't have it supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to get the mouse coordinates, and know the absolute or relative coordinates of the image and its dimensions, you can check circle mouse clicks like so:

The image has a center point, which you can find by doing

```
centerx = image.x + image.width / 2;
centery = image.y + image.height / 2;
```

Of course, `image.width` and `image.height` are equal if the image is a square or circle.

Then you can take your mouse coordinates `mx` and `my` to do the following:

```
//using the Pathagorean Theorem to find the distance 
//between the center point and mouse coordinates
dist = Math.sqrt( (mx - centerx)^2 + (my - centery)^2 );

//checking to see if the distance is less than the radius of the circle
if (dist < image.width / 2){
    //the mouse clicked on the circle
}
```

NOTE: I may have misspelled some of the variables/methods in the code, but still, the general idea is there

EDIT: Trouble Shooting

If this method is producing inaccurate results, it could very well be that the assumptions made for this solution are incorrect. There are several things that could be wrong:

(1) The image is not a square. If the image is not a square, in that its width does not equal its height, then this method won't work.

(2) The mouse coordinates aren't on the same scale as the image coordinates. It might seem strange at first that this could happen, but I've done this before where I have a different coordinate system for my images and another one for my mouse coordinates. In this case, you have to convert the mouse coordinates into the coordinate plane of the image (or vice versa: convert the image coordinates and dimensions into the coordinate plane of the mouse coordinates).

(3) Another thing that could go wrong is that `Math.sqrt` is giving inaccurate results due to rounding and stuff. If this is the case, skip the `sqrt` step and then square the radius. So the code would then look like this:

```
dist2 = (mx - centerx)^2 + (my - centery)^2;   
//checking to see if the distance is less than the radius of the circle
if (dist2 < (image.width / 2)^2 ){
    //the mouse clicked on the circle
}
```

This doesn't work for negative values, but all your distances are going to be positive anyway so it should work

Comment: Hey, I used your method and able to click center region of image (not very accurate, but ok for now). now looking for how to display another image when clicking. thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you! Displaying another image while clicking is easy: while the mouse is being held down, change the button's picture out for another one. One way to do this is to have a mouseClicked varaible or something that you set to true in the mouse down event and set to false in the mouse up event.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need scripting if something like this would work.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/y8GH6/2

```
.img-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.img-circle-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

<div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="#"><div class="img-circle-link"></div></a>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" />
</div>
```

Background color added to the demo for clarity.

Comment: problem is the image is a circle shape, and it keep spanning, like a dart,I tried your suggestion, but did not work. maybe because it is spanning, that is the rason.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what "spanning like a dart" means.

Comment: I mean that image I want to click on center is keep rotating once the web page is open. that image itself is circle shape, it rotates without stopping